# Trash pushed by git in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket, gitignore

I'd like to know what is that trash that was pushed by Android Studio to bitbucket. Those files and directories don't even exist in a project directory. What are they and how can I get rid of them. [BitBucketScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib0qk.png)

.gitignore? If so, why again project directory doesn't contain any of these? 
Greetings.

Comment: `.gitignore` is a file that tells the repo which files to ignore when pushing commits. It can be a useful tool when you have other files in the project directory that you don't want being pushed upstream

Comment: I know. Thing is that when I perform commit&push action (commented in this case "init"), Android Studio do additional unwanted commits which are commented as "AI-2.1.2 <Glaeqen@Glaeqen-Desktop Create ide.general.xml, git.xml, Default.xml, ".. etc. What are these?

Comment: Which files from your screenshot do you think are "trash"?

Comment: @Chris Those marked by commit comment "AI-2.1.2 <Glaeqen@Glaeqen-Desktop Create ide.general.xml, git.xml, Default.xml, " and similar. They have nothing to do with files of actual project.

Comment: Additonaly, directory `_windows` comes out of nowhere as well. Brief explanation why it's there and how to remove it would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. By accident I have setup IDE settings remote repo the same as project one.